# How to end the program and return to the menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to it so that if the user enters a symbol that it is not allowed it ends and returns to the menu. However what happens is it still displays the user's score they got on the password. I want it so that it does not display this if a prohibited symbol is entered. Here is my code:

```
for c in user_password:
  if c not in symbols:
      print("Some symbols you entered are not allowed")
          break   
print(user_score)
```

Comment: I think you want to use ***`in`***  to check if a symbol *has* been entered like `if c in symbols:`, currently you are checking if the `c` is ***not in*** symbols. Also, some of your indentation is off (`break` needs to be unindented to align with the previous `print` statement).

Comment: I wanted it so that the variable `symbols` are allowed. Then if any other character such as `!` or ` ` it should notify the user that these are not allowed and return to the menu.

Comment: Unless someone else understands your requirements better (I don't), maybe include definitions for `user_password` and `symbols`, and an example use case: user input, current invalid output, and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a `raise Exception` of your choice. For example, it seems like you have a ValueError.

So you can write :

```
for c in user_password:
    if c not in symbols:
          raise ValueError("The symbol {} you entered is not allowed".format(c))   
print(user_score)
```

This will make the job.

Note that you can raise *any error* (`KeyError`, `AttributeError`, `IOError` and so) for *any reason*, so for the sake of clarity you have to choose the good test-error and the closer exception to raise.

For example you can list the different symbols that are not allowed.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If `symbols` is just a `list` of *allowed* `characters` such as:

```
symbols = [";", ",", ".", "-"]
```

then even if `user_password` contains only `letters` and these `symbols`, the `print` will still happen as normal `characters` (`letters a-z`) won't be in `symbols`.